# How to implement negative user entry to quit program and print list?

Tags: c++, arrays

My program asks users for non negative entries (negative to quit) repeatedly till they either give a negative value to quit or array is filled. I return the numbers in order without repeats. The only problem is I don't know how to implement the negative entry condition within my loop:

```
    int main(){    
    int arr[ARR_SIZE];    
    int number, arrIndex = 0;
    //gets input

   for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++){
          cout << "Enter a number (negative to quit): ";
          cin >> number;

          if ((!ifExists(arr, 10, number)))
          {
             arr[arrIndex++] = number;
          }   
     }



    for (int i = 0; i < arrIndex; i++) //prints array    
    {
              std::cout << arr[i];    
    }

       return 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this??

```
if (number<0)
return 0;
```

Edit: If you want to continue program execution use `break` instead of `return 0`
You also might want to change the condition in the for loop to `arrIndex<ARR_SIZE` instead of `i < ARR_SIZE;` And you don't need the variable `i`, so I would recommend using the `while` loop. It would be more readible this way, in my opinion.

```
while( arrIndex< ARR_SIZE){
      cout << "Enter a number (negative to quit): ";
      cin >> number;
      if (number<0)
         break;
      if ((!ifExists(arr, 10, number)))
      {
         arr[arrIndex++] = number;
      }   
 }
```

Comment: that ends the code, I still need to print the list. I will split my main into two functions where in I call a getInput and printList.

Comment: This will end the program, not the input. Use `break` instead.

Comment: printList should be after the while loop. not inside. It does not end the program

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break` to exit a loop at a particular point:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++){
      cout << "Enter a number (negative to quit): ";
      cin >> number;

      if (number < 0)
         break;        // exits the for-loop at this point and continues after the loop.

      if ((!ifExists(arr, 10, number)))
      {
         arr[arrIndex++] = number;
      }   
 }

 //... program will continue here after a certain "break"
```